# How to keep HTML generated by Javascript on page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

My question is simple, but I didn't manage to find an answer that fit what I'm looking for. Here's basically my case :

I have a HTML page with a form in it. With jQuery and AJAX, I submit my form, and with some javascript code, I change the HTML content of my div. All this stuff is done without reloading the page while pressing F5 / Ctrl-R / Cmd-R.

Here's an example of the .js code to change the HTML content :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/management/uploadFile",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: "uploadedFile="+uploadedFile,
    cache: false,
    success: 
    function(data){
        $('#mydiv').html(change_html(data));
    },
});

function change_html(data)
{
    var html;

    html += '<div id="mydiv">';
    html += 'Hello World !<br/>';
    html += '</div>';
    return html;
}
```

The fact is that if I reload the page manually, my 'dynamic' HTML content is not kept and I see my form back.

I'm quite new to webdevelopment and I'm sure I missed something about this. Could someone please guide me or give me some tips about my case please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't persist the state of the DOM over a refresh. You can do a number of things to fix though:

1. Look at calling an AJAX method when the page loads that grabs data persisted on the server to redraw your dynamic page.
2. Store the data in the session of the client browser, on reload retrieve that data and redraw your dynamic page. You can achieve this using a number of tools that persist to session storage.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have solved this problem in the past is to use backbone.js models and store any of that data in there.

Answer (score 0):

Since the HTML is dynamically generated using the callback `change_html`, it's not possible to keep it during page reloads. That's the nature of it being well dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance, since you're using ajax anyway, you could just dump the data into a php session and recall it and/or reformat it with ajax when it's needed again?

Comment: I could do that, but I'd like to avoid storing too much things in the session.

Comment: If you have that much data to store from one page to the next, it may be sensible to look into a database to store the data??  Not entirely sure what your application is and what might be most appropriate.